# Как на PowerShell создать и изменить системную переменную среды

Tags: windows, консоль, powershell

Пытаюсь выполнить скрипт от имени администратора под Windows 7

```
$Env:MY_PATH = "$Env:PUBLIC\AppData\Roaming\MySoft"
```

Но переменная не появляется в окно просмотра переменных среды, т.е. не сохраняется.

Так как же с помощью PS создать новую переменную, именно системную?

*UPD*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в текущей сессии PS

```
PS > $env:TestVariable="1"
PS > $env:TestVariable
1
```

если нужно сохранить в сессии пользователя - попробуй вот так:

```
PS > [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "Test value.", "User")
```

только переменная появится в новом порожденном процессе который при перезапуске прочитает карие переменные создавать в своём окружении.

еще "**User**" можно поменять на "**Machine**", "**Process**"

Machine - это и есть система:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "Test value.", "Machine")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но увы это все ни то.    Нужно сохранить в переменных среды системы - т.е. общих системных. Вопрос обновлен - добавлена иллюстрация.

Answer (score 1):

Если это делать в стиле powershell а не C# - то проще всего это делается прямым обращением к реестру.

Переменные окружения текущего пользователя лежат тут:

```
Set-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Environment" MY_PATH "c:\some\path"
```

До системных переменных окружения добираться чуть дольше:

```
Set-ItemProperty "hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" MY_PATH "c:\some\path"
```

Comment: Спасибо, это конечно верно, но манипуляции с реестром не всегда подхватываются до рестарта или релогина. Работа через API в этом плане вернее - ребута ждать не нужно...

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730544/powershell-add-system-variable

```
$variableNameToAdd = "mytestVariableName"
$variableValueToAdd = "some environmental value to add"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```